# having some difficulty with some code around strncmp in C

Tags: c, c-strings, function-definition, ends-with

having some difficulty with some code around strncmp in C just wondering if there is someone that ran into the same problem has me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int endsWith(char* longStr, char* shortStr);

int main()
{
    char* longString = "Grant is The man";
    char* shortString = "man";
    endsWith(longString,shortString);
    printf("%s\n",shortString);
}

int endsWith(char longStr, char shortStr)
{
    int offset;
    for (offset = 0 ; offset < strlen(shortStr) - strlen(longStr) ; offset ++)
        if (strncmp( longStr , shortStr + offset , strlen(longStr)) == 0)
            return 1;

    return -1;
}
```

the return should be man and if i inserted is the nothing should be returned or 0.

Comment: Format the code.

Comment: There's no need to use a loop.

Comment: Your `main` function doesn't care what the `endsWith` function returns. It will print the `shortString` unconditionally.

Comment: Your function takes single char, not string.

Comment: Subtracting a larger value from a shorter value (`strlen(shortStr) - strlen(longStr)`) will be a negative value.  But since `strlen()` returns an unsigned type, a negative will wrap to a very large positive value.

Comment: You also say it should return "0" in some circumstance (your last sentence, "the return should be man and if i inserted is the nothing should be returned or 0." is nonsensical, but I think it at least implies the possibility of returning `0`), but nothing `endsWith` will ever produce a return value of `0` (it's always `1` or `-1`).

Comment: If you use the length of one of the compared strings as limit for `strncmp` there is no reason to use `strncmp` at all. That is only useful if you want to compare less than that.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

- There's no need for a loop. Just get the offset and compare from there once.
- You're calculating the offset backwards. You need to subtract the short length from the long length.
- There's no need to use `strncmp()`, `strcmp()` will work.
- A testing function should return `1` or `0`, not `1` or `-1`.
- You're never checking the result of the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int endsWith(char* longStr, char* shortStr);

int main()
{
    char* longString = "Grant is The man";
    char* shortString = "man";
    if (endsWith(longString,shortString)) {
        printf("%s\n",shortString);
    }
}

int endsWith(char longStr, char shortStr)
{
    int offset = strlen(longStr) - strlen(shortStr);
    if (offset < 0) { // shortStr is longer than longStr
        return 0;
    }
    return strcmp(shortStr, longStr + offset) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the type of the function parameters in the function definition

```
int endsWith(char longStr, char shortStr)
```

does not correspond to the type in the previous function declaration.

At least you need to write in the function definition

```
int endsWith(char *longStr, char *shortStr)
```

But it would be more correct to declare the function like

```
int endsWith( const char *longStr, const char *shortStr );
```

because the passed strings are not changed within the function.

Your approach with the function `strncmp` does not make a great sense.

Moreover this call

```
strncmp( longStr , shortStr + offset , strlen(longStr))
```

is just incorrect. For example why is there used the expression `shortStr + offset`?

If the purpose of the function is to determine whether the first string is ended with the second string then the function can be defined the following way

```
int endsWith( const char *longStr, const char *shortStr );
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( longStr );
    size_t n2 = strlen( shortStr );

    int success = -1;

    if ( !( n1 < n2 ) )
    {
        if ( strcmp( longStr + n1 - n2, shortStr ) == 0 ) success = 1;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Or if you want to return 1 in the case of success or 0 otherwise then the function definition can look like

```
int endsWith( const char *longStr, const char *shortStr );
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( longStr );
    size_t n2 = strlen( shortStr );

    return !( n1 < n2 ) && strcmp( longStr + n1 - n2, shortStr ) == 0;
}
```

Comment: The initial value of `success` should be `0`, not `-1`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In the original code there is returned either 1 or -1.

Comment: yes, but that was wrong logic to begin with. The OP's own description says the function should return 0 if not found.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The description is unclear. I can not understand what this phrase "the return should be man and if i inserted is the nothing should be returned or 0." means.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of problems with your code.

- your declaration of `endsWith()` does not match its definition.
- `main()` is ignoring the return value of `endsWith()`
- there is no need for a loop in `endsWith()` at all.  Your approach is implementing an `indexOf()` function rather than an `endsWith()` function. You can calculate the needed `offset` with a single subtraction, no looping required.

  But, even if a loop were needed, you are not calculating the loop condition correctly. You are subtracting a larger value from a shorter value, which will result in a negative value. But since `strlen()` returns an *unsigned* type, a negative will wrap to a very large positive value, so you end up looping more than you need.
- you are passing the wrong parameters to `strncmp()`.  Since you want to compare the end of the `longStr` to see if it matches the `shortStr`, you need to pass `longStr + offset` instead of `shortStr + offset`, and also pass `strlen(shortStr)` instead of `strlen(longStr)`.
- `endsWith()` should return `0` if a match is not found, not `-1`.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int endsWith(const char* longStr, const char* shortStr);

int main()
{
    const char* longString = "Grant is The man";
    const char* shortString = "man";
    if (endsWith(longString, shortString))
        printf("Ends with %s\n", shortString);
    else
        printf("Does not end with %s\n", shortString);
}

int endsWith(const char* longStr, const char* shortStr)
{
    size_t longLen = strlen(longStr);
    size_t shortLen = strlen(shortStr);
    return (
        (longLen >= shortLen) &&
        (strncmp(longStr + (longLen-shortLen), shortStr, shortLen) == 0)
        ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```